# CakePHP modal not showing after unload 'DebugKit.Toolbar'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp, twitter-bootstrap

Hmmm, I donno how to explain the question actually as its too strange.

```
//Config/bootstrap.php
class AppController extends Controller {
public $components = array(
    'DebugKit.Toolbar',
    'Security' => array('csrfUseOnce' => false,'csrfExpires' => '+1 hour'),
    'Session', 
    //more code below
```

what I've change is removing DebugKit.Toolbar then bootstrap modal is not showing.

```
//default.ctp anchor tag
<li><?=$this->Html->link('Sign in', '/signin',array('data-toggle'=>'modal','data-remote'=>'false','data-target'=>'#signin'));?></li>

//default.ctp modal
<section class="modal fade" id="signin" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Sign in" aria-hidden="true">
    //some other code
</section>

//default.ctp script
</footer>
<?php 
    echo $this->Html->script(array('bootstrap','jquery.min','holder'));
?>
</body>
```

I'm totally confused as how will it possible for unloading a plugin make the bootstrap modal which is irrelevant to not working? Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DebugKit` uses `jQuery`. It's possible that bootstrap used that one, instead of the one you're including in your `layout`.

You might want to include `jquery.min` before bootstrap.

Comment: Omg that solve the problem! I have forgotten bootstrap use jquery haha!